# Socket.io handshake address value changes

Tags: node.js, socket.io

This is peculiar. Socket.io version ~1.3

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Client connected from: ' + socket.handshake.address);
}
```

Returns

> Client connected from: ::1

However

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.handshake);
    console.log('Client connected from: ' + socket.handshake.address);
}
```

Returns

```
{ headers:
   { host: 'localhost:8000',
     connection: 'keep-alive',
     origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTM
L, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36',
     accept: '*/*',
     dnt: '1',
     referer: 'http://localhost:3000/dev.html',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
     'accept-language': 'en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,ko;q=0.4,de;q=0.2,ru;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2,ja;q=0.2,it;q=0.2',
     cookie: 'io=yhyuAabou3GufhzNAAAA' },
  time: 'Wed Jun 24 2015 22:50:19 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)',
  address: '::ffff:127.0.0.1',
  xdomain: true,
  secure: false,
  issued: 1435179019584,
  url: '/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1435179017804-3',
  query: { EIO: '3', transport: 'polling', t: '1435179017804-3' } }
Client connected from: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
```

Why? Is there some ES6 proxy in the way? I thought maybe some weird JS conversion magic was in place, but it doesn't seem like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::ffff:127.0.0.1` is an IPv6 version of `127.0.0.1` and `::1` is an IPv6 shortcut for both.

See [Express.js req.ip is returning ::ffff:127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411551/express-js-req-ip-is-returning-ffff127-0-0-1) for a similar question.

Comment: Thank you. Could you point me as to where the conversion happens, and why it happens only when I dump the whole handshake object? I got as far as https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L595 , so maybe this is dependent from console.log implementation?

Comment: I tracked it further down to https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/pipe_wrap.cc but my C++ and OS api/pipes knowledge is not enough.