# Express.js- Why is Localhost '::'

Tags: node.js, express, localhost

Can anyone tell me why my server address (host) is :: and not localhost

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made to the homepage
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hello world');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

This returns

```
Example app listening at http://:::3000
```

It works fine when I go to http://localhost:3000/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because :: is localhost when using IPv6, just like it is 127.0.0.1 in IPv4.

Comment: Ah ha. Is IPv6 the standard in Express then? Is there any way to toggle between the two?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411551/express-js-req-ip-is-returning-ffff127-0-0-1