# How do you print the address of an http server in node.js?

Tags: node.js, web-services, http, ip-address

Here is my code:

```
var http = require('http');

function onRequest(req, res) {
    // do something
}

var server = http.createServer(onRequest);
server.listen(8000);
console.log("The server is now running on " + <<server.address>>);
```

I want the <> to be something like "http://localhost:8000". How do I do that?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853695/node-js-server-address-address-returns) might be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server listening:', `http://${server.address().address}:${server.address().port}`);
```

I think you can use

> server.address()#
>
> Added in: v0.1.90 Returns the bound address, the address family name,
>   and port of the server as reported by the operating system. Useful to
>   find which port was assigned when getting an OS-assigned address.
>   Returns an object with port, family, and address properties: { port:
>   12346, family: 'IPv4', address: '127.0.0.1' }

Answer (score 1):

This should give you your hostname and port on server startup:

```
var server  = require('http').createServer(onRequest);
var port = '8000';
server.listen(port, function(err) {
    console.log(err, require('os').hostname()+':'+port);
});
```