# How can I get the correct ip address of the visitor in node.js? (I tried node-ip and it doesn't work)

Tags: node.js

I'm using a node ip taken from here: https://github.com/indutny/node-ip

In my webservice I did a simple thing:

```
var ip              = require('ip');

module.exports = function(app) {

app.get('/gps', function (req, res) {

    console.log(ip.address());
}
}
```

I deployed it to my amazon aws account and now whoever enters the page - I constantly see the same ip address in my console log - `172.31.46.96`. I tried to check what is this ip (possible option is that it is related to my amazon aws service?), but who.is does not bring the answer.

How should I change my code to see every visitor's ip address instead?

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely getting an IP of an internal load balancer/proxy and you'll need to configure express to handle that.

[This is a good place to start.](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html)

Comment: So I tried to add `app.set('trust proxy', 'loopback, 172.31.46.96')` to my `server.js` file but it didn't help, could you give me some hints what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does `app.set('trust proxy')`, then using `req.ip` instead of using the node-ip package produce the desired output? If not, do the request headers yield any clues (eg: `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']`)?

Comment: Thanks, I think it worked with `trust proxy` and `req.ip`! Just one more question - now when I'm doing `console.log("coordinates"+req.ip)` I'm getting `coordinates::ffff:188.164.244.110` - why is there the `ffff` and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411551/express-js-req-ip-is-returning-ffff127-0-0-1, you're getting an IPv6 prefix along with your IPv4 address. This library will help if you want to map that to an IPv4 address: https://github.com/whitequark/ipaddr.js

Answer (score 0):

Use `req.connection.remoteAddress` to get the ip of your user.