# How can I find the string and split it in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, split

I have a value like this `::ffff:127.0.0.1` but i need only `127.0.0.1`. Is there a way to search the string in node.js?

Basically I want to match the ip that why I need to split the above        string

> After splitting I need to check in database so its compulsory for me to split the above string. The value wold be always like `::ffff:137.3.3.1`,  so I need a `stringSplitter` function which will split all of my given inputs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411551/express-js-req-ip-is-returning-ffff127-0-0-1

Comment: i didn't get this on above link i need to remove the prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Mukesh Sharma is right. But if you don't want to install any npm module and keep things simple you can do this -

```
function splitString(stringToSplit, separator) {
  var arrayOfStrings = stringToSplit.split(separator); // [ '', '', 'ffff', '127.0.0.1' ]
  return arrayOfStrings[3];
}

var yourString = "::ffff:127.0.0.1"; // or any other
var colon = ":";
var newIP = splitString(yourString, colon); // '127.0.0.1'
```

I think this would help you. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

`::ffff:127.0.0.1` is IPv6 ip address in which `::ffff:` is a subnet prefix for IPv4 (32 bit) addresses that are placed inside an IPv6 (128 bit) space

If you want to extract out `127.0.0.1`from `::ffff:127.0.0.1`, you can use `ipaddr.js` module.

`npm install ipaddr.js`

Sample code to extract out IPv4 using `ipaddr.js`

```
var ipaddr = require('ipaddr.js');
var addr = ipaddr.parse("::ffff:127.0.0.1");

//if this address is an IPv4-mapped one
if(addr.isIPv4MappedAddress()){
    //then, convert to IPv4 address
    var newAddr= addr.toIPv4Address().toString(); 
    console.log(newAddr); // 127.0.0.1
}
```

Hopes, it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = '::ffff:127.0.0.1'
var search = a.search('127.0.0.1')

if (search !== -1){
   var newIP1 = a.replace("::ffff:","")
   console.log(newIP1)
       //// OR ////
   var newIP2 = a.split("::ffff:")[1]
   console.log(newIP2)
}
```